# Make expandable div start closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/P3pJ6/161/) code which, when the 'A' is clicked, extra content comes down. But, I want the extra content to start hidden. How would I do this?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<section class="box2">
    <header class="box-head">
        <div class="box-title fr"> <span class="box-icon"></span>

        </div>  <a class="box-toggle fl active" href="#">A</a>

    </header>
    <div class="box-content active">
        Content</div>
</section>
```

Javascript:

```
$("a.box-toggle").on('click', function () {
    $('div.box-content').slideToggle(200).toggleClass('active');
});
```

CSS:

```
.widget-toggle {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 9px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    background: url(../img/sidebar-arrows.png) no-repeat 0 -18px;
}
.widget-toggle.active {
    background: url(../img/sidebar-arrows.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `.box-content` elements to `display: none` in CSS by default:

```
.box-content {
    display: none;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/P3pJ6/163/)

Comment: This might sometimes fail. Better to do with jQuery or inline styles.

Comment: Under what circumstances? CSS is more reliable, and inline styles should be avoided where possible

Comment: Had personal issues. Lemme replicate one for you... `:)` The reason behind being, jQuery checks for `style="display: none"` present or not, and based on that the first click doesn't work.

Comment: [This](http://output.jsbin.com/jitidoviza) supposed to **not work** but surprisingly it works. `:P` Lemme check in other versions.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the bug. jQuery has evolved! `:P`

Answer (score 2):

Use this way. Replace your code:

```
$("a.box-toggle").on('click', function () {
    $('div.box-content').slideToggle(200).toggleClass('active');
});
```

With the following:

```
$('div.box-content').hide();
$("a.box-toggle").on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest(".box-head").next('div.box-content').slideToggle(200).toggleClass('active');
});
```

The reason for change is, if you have multiple `.box-head`, then it will trigger the slide on everything and not just one.